# Compilation error: 'struct net_device’ has no member named ‘open’

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I am following LDD3 for learning network device driver. I just compiled the source code of snull driver and I got this compilation error:

```
error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘open’
```

I also got similar error when I try to initialize other members of struct `net_device`. Please help to resolve this error.

Below is the code:

```
struct net_device *snull_devs[2];
snull_devs[0] = alloc_netdev(sizeof(struct snull_priv), "sn%d",
                    snull_init);

void snull_init(struct net_device *dev)
{
    ether_setup(dev); /* assign some of the fields */

    dev->open            = snull_open;
    dev->stop            = snull_release;
```

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: struct net_device *dev;
 snull_devs[0] = alloc_netdev(sizeof(struct snull_priv), "sn%d",
                        snull_init);

void snull_init(struct net_device *dev)
{
        ether_setup(dev); /* assign some of the fields */

        dev->open            = snull_open;
        dev->stop            = snull_release;

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question so you can format it readably.

Comment: @Barmar, Please find the above code, declaration of snull_dev is struct net_device *snull_devs[2];

Comment: See the structure declaration at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/netdevice.h#L1607. There's no `open` member. What makes you think that's the correct way to use it?

Comment: Yes, I too saw that. But I am a newbie to device driver and as I said I am following LDD3 for writing this driver. I assumed that the author would not have done anything wrong and there is something that I may miss in my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That book is pretty old, and this has apparently changed in more recent kernels. `struct net_device` now has the following member:

```
    const struct net_device_ops *netdev_ops;
```

This has members like:

```
    int                     (*ndo_open)(struct net_device *dev);
    int                     (*ndo_stop)(struct net_device *dev);
```

So the equivalent code would be:

```
dev->netdev_ops->ndo_open = snull_open;
dev->netdev_ops->ndo_stop = snull_release;
```

But there could be other changes to the device driver environment that affect how this should be coded. I suggest you read the chapter [API changes in the 2.6 kernel series](https://lwn.net/Articles/2.6-kernel-api/).